# JavaScript Date equal to 'NaN' in IE

Tags: javascript, date, internet-explorer

I have a date function that converts `HTML` form input into a date in milliseconds. It works in all browsers except Internet explorer.

Is the `JavaScript` Date function not functional in IE?

The code below should give you **1521032400** in FF and Chrome but **NaN** in IE11

**Code**

```js
var startTime = '9:00 AM';
var startDate = "2018-03-14";

var dateInMilli = new Date(startDate + " " + startTime.split(' ')[0]).getTime() / 1000;

alert(dateInMilli);
```

Comment: `Date` definitely works in IE; it probably just doesn't like the format you're using. Which "IE" are you testing with? IE11? Older?

Comment: @Pointy if you run that code snippet in IE11/10/9 it'll return NaN.

Comment: I don't have an IE11 handy, but try sticking with `2018-03-14T09:00:00-04:00`.

Comment: It also returns an invalid date in Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you use isn't standard, so IE11 doesn't have to understand it.

Use the following format instead:

```
new Date("2018-03-14T09:00")
```

Comment: No, don't do that either. It should be treated as local, but Safari treats it as UTC. Please follow the advice in the duplicate: **do not use the built-in parser**. Manually parse date strings with a custom function or library.

Comment: @RobG: Is there any reason for not using `Date.parse` with full ISO 8601 (i.e. with TZ specifier)?

Comment: @Amadan—it's probably OK now in most browsers, but in the Internet of Things there are vastly more implementations than just the popular handful of browsers that most can name, so I would avoid it. A parser for a single format is only a few lines of code, so why not?

Answer (score 2):

The Date function does work in IE, it's just more finicky about what strings it accepts. If you format your string to the RFC2822 standard ("Wed, 14 Mar 2018 09:30:00 GMT") or the ISO standard ("2018-03-14T09:00:00") you should be ok in any browser.

Comment: Emphasise the word "should". It doesn't "work" correctly in Safari at least, and RFC2822 formatting is only supported in the latest version of ECMA-262: ECMAScript 2018, so ubiquitous support can't be assumed.